# ignore a file name in php array

Tags: php, arrays

im pretty new with php, i found a gallery script that takes all photos from a folder and displays them. I'm trying to make the array ignore all folders in this 'photos' folder named 'app_thumbnails'.

the code creating the array is:

```
//READ FILES AND FOLDERS
$files = array();
$dirs = array();
 if ($handle = opendir($currentdir))
 {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
// Change filename to display date
        $displaydate= date('jS M Y', strtotime($file));
// Load folders into array
        if (is_directory($currentdir . "/" . $file))
            { 
                if ($file != "." && $file != ".." )
                {
// Set thumbnail to folder.jpg if found:
                    if (file_exists(GALLERY_ROOT . "photos/" . $file . "/folder.jpg"))
                    {
                        $dirs[] = array(
                            "name" => $file,
                            "date" => filemtime($currentdir . "/" . $file),
                            "html" => "<li><a href='?dir=" . urlencode(ltrim($_GET['dir'] . "/" . $file, "/")) . "'><em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $displaydate . "</em><span></span><img src='" . GALLERY_ROOT . "createthumb.php?filename=photos/" . $file . "/folder.jpg&amp;size=$thumb_size'  alt='$label_loading' /></a></li>");
                    }  else
                    {
//Set thumbnail to first image found (if any):
                        unset ($firstimage);
                        $firstimage = getfirstImage("$currentdir/" . $file);
                        if ($firstimage != "") {
                        $dirs[] = array(
                            "name" => $file,
                            "date" => filemtime($currentdir . "/" . $file),
                            "html" => "<li><a href='?dir=" . urlencode(ltrim($_GET['dir'] . "/" . $file, "/")) . "'><em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $displaydate . "</em><span></span><img src='" . GALLERY_ROOT . "createthumb.php?filename=$thumbdir/" . $file . "/" . $firstimage . "&amp;size=$thumb_size'  alt='$label_loading' /></a></li>");
                        } else {
//If no folder.jpg or image is found, then display default icon:
                            $dirs[] = array(
                                "name" => $file,
                                "date" => filemtime($currentdir . "/" . $file),
                                "html" => "<li><a href='?dir=" . urlencode(ltrim($_GET['dir'] . "/" . $file, "/")) . "'><em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $displaydate . "</em><span></span><img src='" . GALLERY_ROOT . "images/folder_" . strtolower($folder_color) . ".png' width='$thumb_size' height='$thumb_size' alt='$label_loading' /></a></li>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

you can see my gallery example here: http://design-wright.co.uk/bunker/gallery/gallery.php

thanks for your time guys.
alsweet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try replacing the following:

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." )
```

by

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'app_thumbnails')
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." )
```

with

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "app_thumbnails")
```